# I am building my pc and have some issues with providing power

Tags: power-supply, desktop-computer

My Computer is using overall 311 W calculated on cooler master and i am using a 550 W corsair power supply for it, so can i use a ups with 360 W power supply

Comment: If your overall power input can reach near 600 W , you need about a 750 W UPS to provide proper power in an outage.

Answer (score 0):

When looking at a battery backup, it is important to consider the On-Battery runtime you require, as well as the largest load potential. In addition to the computer itself, you may want some peripherals on the battery. Your primary monitor should definitely be considered, and maybe your networking equipment. Your monitor will help you manage whatever you were doing when the battery intervened, and having the network equipment on battery will prevent loss of connectivity during a brief power outage, where you don't need anything to shutdown.

The major UPS manufacturers have usage calculators on their websites where you can enter in a potential load or the devices you want to use, and your preferred battery runtime. Using these parameters, they try to match you up with some options.

At APC, I put in a load of 400W, with a 5 min runtime, and received these options:

[APC Options](https://www.apc.com/shop/us/en/tools/ups_selector/home/load/recommendations?power=400&powerUnit=w&operatingVoltage=120&voltageScheme=singlePhase&runtime=5&powerMargin=0&pageNumber=1&sortOption=PRICE_ASC)